Extending/lifting problem for abelian group endomorphisms on subgroups/quotients
Let $A$ be an abelian group and $B$ a subgroup of $A$. Suppose $\sigma: A \to A$ is such that $\sigma(B) \subseteq B$, then it induces a map $\tilde{\sigma}: A/B \to A/B$.
I am interested in finding simple counterexamples (or proving the corresponding results, although I believe counterexamples should exist) to the following questions:

Given $\tau \in \text{End}(B)$, does there exist $\sigma \in \text{End}(A)$ such that $\sigma|_B = \tau$?

Given $\tau \in \text{End}(A/B)$, does there exist $\sigma \in \text{End}(A)$ such that $\tilde{\sigma} = \tau$?

Given $\tau \in \text{Aut}(B)$, does there exist $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(A)$ such that $\sigma|_B = \tau$?

Given $\tau \in \text{Aut}(A/B)$, does there exist $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(A)$ such that $\tilde{\sigma} = \tau$?


A counterexample for Question 3 has already been constructed in this question, which is quite clever. It was after seeing this counterexample that I was prompted to ask about the other cases, since a simple search did not lead me to find counterexamples for the other three questions on MSE. I think this is a very natural question and should be asked by someone.
Specifically, I am not sure if this problem can be viewed from a "higher perspective" using homological algebra methods.

Please focus on one question only, see here. The linked dupe (that I found with Approach Zero) answers questions 1 and 2, and you already answered 4. Maybe the given answer to 2 also answers 3, but I didn't check. In any case it should be separate. But probably there is also an exact duplicate of 3.

Homological interpretation: only possible if $B$ is fully invariant so that your question is about a surjectivity of certain maps. But fully invariant subgroups of abelian groups are rare. Also the maps are not additive. So it's unlikely.

True. The linked examples solve all questions. One only need to figure out all endomorphism of $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, which is easy.
